# How to use data in a text file?

Tags: r, raster

Given three rasters, I need to extract values corresponding to `u` (row) = 5 and `c` (column) from a text file `smoke`.

```
smoke <- matrix(c(5, 4, 2, 9, 2, 2), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

The function I'm using is:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))

func <- function(c, u, sit){
  rasters <- mget(c('r', paste0('r', 1:2)))
  x <- sapply(rasters, function(x) getValues(x, c)[u])
  y <- sapply(rasters, function(x) getValues(x, u)[c])
  g <- data.frame(y, x)
  write.table(g, paste0("res_", sit, u, "_", c, ".txt"))
}
```

Here's how I use the function to extract values that correspond to `c` and `u` in `smoke`:

```
res <- lapply(split(smoke[,c('c', 'u', 'sit')], 1:nrow(smoke)), 
              FUN=function(x) func(c=x[1], u=x[2], sit=x[3]))
```

I get this error: `error: value for ‘r’ not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `mget` only looks for the objects `r`, `r1`, and `r2` in the environment in which it's called, but in your case, those objects are in the global environment. You can either add `inherits=TRUE` to the `mget` call, which will force it to keep looking in parent environments, or else specify the environment to look in with `envir=.GlobalEnv`.

You have a couple of other problems, though.

First, `r1` and `r2` don't exist in your example.

Second, the list arising from `split` is a list of data frames, and you need to index them accordingly in your function. This means either using `$` notation (e.g. `x$c`), double brackets (e.g. `x[[1]]`), or use a comma (e.g. `x[, 1]`).

Implementing all of this, you should have something like:

```
func <- function(c, u, sit) {
  rasters <- mget(c('r', paste0('r', 1:2)), envir=.GlobalEnv)
  x <- sapply(rasters, function(x) getValues(x, c)[u])
  y <- sapply(rasters, function(x) getValues(x, u)[c])
  g <- data.frame(y, x)
  write.table(g, paste0("res_", sit, u, "_", c, ".txt"))
}

library(raster)
res <- lapply(split(smoke[, c('c', 'u', 'sit')], 1:nrow(smoke)), 
              function(x) func(c=x[[1]], u=x[[2]], sit=x[[3]]))
```

Finally, `res` will just be a list of `NULL` values, since your function returns the value of `write.table`, which is `NULL`. If you want `func` to return `g`, then add a final line to the function that simply reads `g` (or, explicitly, `return(g)`).

I'm not sure how closely your small example reflects your true data, but you could probably approach this more efficiently - see `?extract`, `?cellFromRowCol`, and `?stack`, for example.

Comment: @temor - I would bet that your error now says `Error: value for ‘r1’ not found`. I mentioned above that `r1` and `r2` don't exist in your example. Add `r1 <- r2 <- r` after you create `r`, and it should work fine.